# Use apple TV remote as the *only* remote for a TV

Tags: appletv, siri-remote

I would like to purchase an Apple TV and an accompanying TV. I will use the Apple TV and tvOS as the *only* software to watch anything on that TV.
Is there a way to be able to use the remote of the Apple TV always as the *only remote ever*, so that I can I turn the TV and the Apple TV on and off with the Apple remote only. Ideally even if both have been completely disconnected from power?

I really would like to avoid having to deal with two remotes and doing weird dances, turning stuff on and off and selecting the right input source.

When purchasing a TV what do I need to watch out for to make that happen?

Comment: Looking at this the other way round: my Samsung TV remote works with my Apple TV box.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a second-gen Apple TV 4K with the Siri Remote, you can control TV, receiver, volume, etc.

- HDMI-CEC support is the feature that allows the new Siri Remote to power your TV and receiver on/off, control volume, and select the right input. The old Siri Remote and Apple TV Remote also feature this functionality, but without a dedicated power button, it’s less convenient and intuitive to use.

Extracted from: https://9to5mac.com/2021/05/27/apple-tv-siri-remote-control-tv-receiver/

Comment: +1 for this. My 2nd gen ATV 4K does this with my LG TV. It’s absolutely brilliant. I also setup HomePod minis with it, so I can just say, “Hey, Siri, turn on the TV” too, without using the remote.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it - unless you can programme in *one* input, no peripherals except those two devices, no aerial, no cable box, no AVR amp… then you *might* have a chance.
20 years ago when everything worked on infra-red, you could get devices that could 'steal' a set of controller commands by literally pointing one at the other. I had one. It was great, though it took about 6 'pages' of data display on its screen [about the size of a modern iPhone] & sometimes when I wanted to start the DVD player, instead it would switch the radio on. Such was technology back then.

Then companies started using a 'family' of infra-red command sets, so you could get smart remotes with all these 'families' pre-loaded - though you'd still have to manually switch between them, using TV/CD/DVD/HiFi etc buttons on the remote.

Now we've got 'smarter' we've not moved on much at all…
Some remotes still use infra red. Some use Wifi, some use bluetooth.
There's another push to try gain full control over HDMI known as eARC [which needs *all* equipment to be compatible.

So 20 years on, I can programme my 'video recorder' [or my lights or heating] from anywhere in the world using my phone, and watch what it recorded too. I have one remote that will switch my entire rig on & off, and successfully control the AVR amp's volume from any of the **four** remotes I still have on my sofa…
Everything else still needs just a couple of buttons from each of the four to build the complete control suite. The other 30 buttons sit there unused.

[Apple KB on eARC](https://support.apple.com/HT207117)

Nearly forgot about this one, you'll need as well - [HDMI-CEC](https://www.howtogeek.com/234324/how-to-set-your-apple-tv-to-automatically-turn-your-television-or-media-center-on/)

<sup>Sorry if this sounds cynical. I've spent literally 20 years trying to have such a system, one remote for everything. It's always 'just around the corner'. I'm down to just 4 things interconnected - TV, Mac, AVR, cable box… gone is the CD player, DVD, Blu-ray, Radio receiver, video recorder… & I still can't do it. [My TV can do Apple TV so I've never gone for *yet another* separate device.]</sup>